# Power Automate - Invalid Expression

Tags: power-automate

This is a simple question, but is doing my head in, where I can't see what is wrong with the following expression in Power Automate:

```
concat(variables('ID'),"-",variables('Name')," Outcome.pdf")
```

It returns the below saying "The expression is invalid". Can anyone see what is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'` for strings not `"`.

```
concat(variables('ID'), '-', variables('Name'), ' Outcome.pdf')
```